# How to find out shared memory and global memory size of GPU?

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, gpu, shared-memory, gpgpu

I want to know what is the shared memory and global memory size of my GPU. I am using nvidia tesla k40c. I found [this link](http://m.ncix.com/products/features/94978) and it says standard memory is 12 GB. Is standard memory the same thing as global memory? How can I find size of shared memory? is there any command that shows gpu features? I used **nvidia-smi** command but it didn't give information about memory sizes. How can I find out memory sizes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the standard memory in your link is global memory.

There's a program `deviceQuery` in CUDA samples, which shows the info you need. You could find it in CUDA dir, typically in  `/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`. The following document also tells you how to build it.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#device-query